# ggplot2: counts precentage line chart for factor groups in date-series dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

My data is a research result record. It contains two groups (group1 and group2), three results(positive, neutral, and negative). Also, it is a time-series dataset, so it has the date variable(day1, day2, ...)

Here is an example of my data:

```
Book1 %>% head(n=20)
# A tibble: 20 x 4
      No Group Result   date 
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>
 1     1     1 positive day1 
 2     2     1 neutral  day1 
 3     3     1 neutral  day1 
 4     4     2 negative day1 
 5     5     2 positive day1 
 6     6     2 neutral  day1 
 7     7     1 neutral  day1 
 8     8     1 negative day1 
 9     9     1 positive day1 
10    10     2 neutral  day1 
11    11     1 neutral  day2 
12    12     1 negative day2 
13    13     1 positive day2 
14    14     2 neutral  day2 
15    15     2 neutral  day2 
16    16     2 negative day2 
17    17     1 positive day2 
18    18     1 positive day2 
19    19     1 positive day2 
20    20     2 positive day2
```

I plan to draw a line chart to compare the result rate (positive rate, neutral rate, and negative rate) between two groups, so my code is:

```
Book1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), fill = Group)) +
  geom_line(stat = "count") +
  facet_grid(Result~.)
```

However, I receive much warning information:

```
geom_path: Each group consists of only one
observation. Do you need to adjust the group
aesthetic?
```

and the plot contains nothing. here is the plot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poya5.png)

I don't know why I get this result and how to do to get the correct plot.

Comment: The  column name is not matching i.e. it should be `date` instead of `Date`

Comment: When you do the summarisation, there would be a single value per group.  Do you need `geom_col` instead of `geom_line`

Answer (score 0):

`geom_line` expects more than one observation.  AFter summarization, there would be a single element per group.  Instead of `geom_line`, `geom_col` or `geom_bar` would be useful

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
Book1 %>% 
     group_by(date, Group = factor(Group), Result) %>%
     summarise(value = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
     mutate(perc = value/sum(value)) %>% 
     ggplot(aes(x = date, y = perc, fill = Group)) + 
            geom_col() +
            facet_grid(~ Result)
```

-output

[image]

---

Or if we use the `..count..`

```
Book1 %>% 
     mutate(Group = factor(Group)) %>%
     ggplot(aes(x = date)) + 
        geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), fill = Group)) +
        facet_grid(~ Result)
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
Book1 <- structure(list(No = 1:20, Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), Result = c("positive", 
"neutral", "neutral", "negative", "positive", "neutral", "neutral", 
"negative", "positive", "neutral", "neutral", "negative", "positive", 
"neutral", "neutral", "negative", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
"positive"), date = c("day1", "day1", "day1", "day1", "day1", 
"day1", "day1", "day1", "day1", "day1", "day2", "day2", "day2", 
"day2", "day2", "day2", "day2", "day2", "day2", "day2")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A line plot is possible and depends on how you sketch the summaries for your data. You can see the evolution by day per group using a code of this style:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Code
df %>% group_by(Group,Result,date) %>%
  summarise(N=n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=date,y=N,group=Result,color=Result))+
  geom_line(size=1)+
  geom_point(size=1)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,NA))+
  facet_grid(.~Group)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        strip.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'))
```

Output:

[image]

It is a really interesting approach using lines to see how trends in results change.

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(No = 1:20, Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), Result = c("positive", 
"neutral", "neutral", "negative", "positive", "neutral", "neutral", 
"negative", "positive", "neutral", "neutral", "negative", "positive", 
"neutral", "neutral", "negative", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
"positive"), date = c("day1", "day1", "day1", "day1", "day1", 
"day1", "day1", "day1", "day1", "day1", "day2", "day2", "day2", 
"day2", "day2", "day2", "day2", "day2", "day2", "day2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Or using percentages you can try:

```
#Code 2
df %>% group_by(Group,Result,date) %>%
  summarise(N=n()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Group) %>% mutate(Perc=N/n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=date,y=Perc,group=Result,color=Result))+
  geom_line(size=1)+
  geom_point(size=1)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,NA),labels = scales::percent)+
  facet_grid(.~Group)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        strip.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Duck. Your answer is so amazing!!

Comment: @Carlos Great! I hope this helped you!! It was a good thinking question!